# Orchard 1.3 check if property exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I just want to know if it is possible to check if an attribute/property exists in a object

Something like:

```
if(widgetPart.RenderTitle.GetType().ToString() != null) {...}
```

or

```
String.isNullOrEmpty(widgetPart.RenderTitle)
```

Its giving me

> 'Orchard.Widgets.Models.WidgetPart' does not contain a definition for
>   'RenderTitle' and no extension method 'RenderTitle'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my solution like this:

```
var renderTitleObj = ((IContent)Model.ContentItem).As<WidgetPart>();
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfoSrcObj = renderTitleObj.GetType().GetProperty("RenderTitle");
if (propInfoSrcObj != null) { renderTitle = Convert.ToBoolean(propInfoSrcObj.GetValue(renderTitleObj, null)); }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use reflection or better, check WidgetPart for the available members before you use them. That won't even compile.